# Unable to load the requested file - codeigniter on hostmonster server

Tags: php, codeigniter, hostmonster

I've been trying to host an application design with codeigniter framework for days on at hostmonster.com but I continued having this disturbing error -

**An Error Was Encountered
Unable to load the requested file: Desktop\resourceBatch\stylesheets.php**

> NB: Desktop\resourceBatch\stylesheets.php is a directory I manually
>   created within my "view" folder

Though the same application is working perfectly on my local machine.

Comment: Could you provide more information? Do you get the error when trying to upload or do you get it by codeigniter? could you put up an print screen?

Comment: The apache server is case sensitive. Make sure all are in the proper case.

Comment: @ISuthanBala how do you mean case sensitive

Comment: The filenames must be of the same case ie. `MY_Controller` should be contained within the file `MY_Controller.php` NOT my_controller. So be sure you are matching the cases properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me months to figure this out. Avoid these mistakes.

1. I removed all capital letters on my folder names e.g

   `Desktop\resourceBatch\stylesheets.php` 
    to

   `desktop\resourcebatch\stylesheets.php`

2.
   changed all `\` to `/`

```
$this->load->view('desktop\resourcebatch\stylesheets.php');
```

to

```
   $this->load->view('desktop/resourcebatch/stylesheets.php');
```